# Visual studio UWP solution prompted "app didn't start" error after moving solution folder

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I moved my solution folder to somewhere else and moved it back to its old location, for which the reason is too complicated to explain. But now it says myApp.exe process has started but "app didn't start" when I run it in debug mode. All builds succeeded. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't think that you'll get the answer at all. For the start there is no .exe file in UWP...

Comment: the error says unable to launch windows store app myApp.exe has started, but the activation request failed with error 'the app didn't start'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the app runs successfully once I deleted the obj and bin folders in my solution folder.